# Adobe AIR: How do I bring NativeWindow in front of modal dialog?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have a native window which opens up a url. That window is launched from a hyperlink present on a modal dialog. Native window always appears behind the modal dialog.

how can bring native window in front of the modal dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set **alwaysInFront** property to **true**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                           creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[

                import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                {
                    nativeWindow.alwaysInFront = true;
                }

            ]]>
        </fx:Script>

    </s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying orderToFront() which did not help.

Comment: your are welcome, for orderToFront it move a window in front of all other windows in the application (that only affects windows owned by application )

Comment: Thank you, I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

ALSO,

If anyone is building an AIR application and happens to run into an issue that when you open a new window, it opens, yet is still behind other things....Try this.

```
nativeWindow.alwaysInFront = true;
nativeWindow.activate();
nativeWindow.alwaysInFront = false;
```

This works because according to the docs:

Changing alwaysInFront from false to true will bring the window to the top of all other windows. Changing the property from true to false will send the window to the back of "alwaysInFront" windows, but still in front of other windows.